# i have a mist twst can case but the date on the bottom of it shows dec 19 2016

Tags: drinks

i brought a mist twist 355 ml soda can case. But the date on the bottom of it shows December 19 2016, i could not know if it is an expiration date or manufacturing date and kindly let me know if i still can drink it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is an expiration date, Dec. 19, 2016 is only a little over a month ago. If the cans are sealed, the soda inside can't possibly have gotten significantly more toxic than it was on the good-until date, just by aging for 34 more days. Go ahead & drink it.

[stilltasty.com](http://www.stilltasty.com/searchitems/search/soda) is a good reference.